# In update method, query parameter containing a list (pymongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a dictionary. I need to insert column 2 into mongodb corresponding to column 1(key).

Say this is the dictionary:

```
values = {'a':['1','2','3'],
          'b':['1','2'],
          'c':['3','4'] }
```

Right now I am doing this:

```
for k,v in values.items():
col4.update({"name":k},{"$set":{"fieldName":v}})
```

But this takes 3 accesses to the db. Is it possible to do it one go like the way $in works.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are finding each document by `name` field and set its `fieldName` to `v`. There is no `update` operation in Mongo that can do such thing in one shot for multiple documents.

However there is a bulk insert statement which can be more efficient than multiple inserts or updates. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/.

I thinks I previously didn't quite understand what you were asking and wrote the answer below, but I'm still not sure what you mean by `$in`. Perhaps you can provide example of data before and after update in DB, that way it will be absolutely clear what you are trying to achieve.

OLD answer ... (I'll edit it soon)

You need to restructure your loop. Build up a query (not running) by adding `{field: newValue}` to `$set` clause. After the loop is done you will have an analog of `{$set:{"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 3}}`. Then you will update all fields in one shot.

Here is official documentation:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: let me know if you need pymongo syntax